# Td left border not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply border styling to td but its not showing left border,

It works fine in some browser but does not work on other.

HTML,

```
<table class="table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Tow</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
            <th>Five</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Interactions -

```
$("tbody > tr > td").on("hover", function (event) {

    var columnIndex = $(this).index() + 1;

    $(this).closest("tbody").find('tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').toggleClass('bordered', event.type === "mouseenter");

    $("table").find('tr th:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').toggleClass('coloured', event.type === "mouseenter");

});
```

CSS -

```
td.bordered {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}

th.coloured {
    background: #e8e8e8;
    color: black;
}

table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:auto;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    border:1px solid #999999;
}
th {
    font: bold 11px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #F2EDEB;
    border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
    background: #522D25 url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
tr {
    background: #fff;
    color: #261F1D;
}
tr:hover, tr.alt:hover {
    color: #261F1D;
    background-color: #E5C37E;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #000;    
}
```

### Testing environment Details

Google Chrome - Version 45.0.2454.85 m

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/03qf9d3p/1/)

Comment: where is it failing... which browsers it is working and where it is not

Comment: In the title it is *right border*, in the question it is *left border*; which is it?

Comment: @MKA it works...but what was the exact issue

Comment: It is working fine for all the `td`s except you are not able to visualize it since **right border** of previous `td` is overlapping on **left border** of next `td`. You can identify it if you see the first `td` where both the borders get effected.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao caught it right...Thumbs up for in details description.. Please post your anse

Comment: This may be Browser issue Upgrade your Browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I see that it is working fine for all the `td`s but you are not able to visualize it since **right border** of previous `td` is overlapping on **left border** of next `td`. You can identify it if you see the first `td` where both the **borders** get effected.

What I would suggest is try providing space between two `td`s and then I think you can visualize it properly. Not sure though whether `padding` or `margin` works on `td`.

---

**UPDATE**

As @Tushar said you can remove `border-collapse` property from `table` and below you can identify the changes.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/03qf9d3p/4/)**

Comment: `border-collapse:collapse;` can be removed then